# Redirecting URL without www to www

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I need your help. I want to test if the URL is entered without www

like `example.com` it should be forwarded to `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: note: this will also redirect something.example.com to www.example.com

Comment: @Piskvor: No, it will redirect it to *www.something.example.com*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what does i means R=301?

Comment: @basit74: The *R* flag forces an external redirect and *301* is the status code of the response.

Comment: I stand corrected.
@basit74: R=301 means HTTP Redirect with code 301 (Moved Permanently).

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com/$0 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `nginx`, then add this line to `nginx config`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name yourdomain.com;
  rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 permanent;
}
```