# Font-face don't display well

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox, cross-browser

I have a wordpress site here http://itrain.com.my/v3/ as my Home Page

I am wondering why it is not displaying well in Firefox?

Anyone who is good in css?

By the way, try to look at the subpages http://www.itrain.com.my/v3/index.php/about-us/

it display well.

I am really wondering why does it happening.

Any can help me? Any suggestion, recommendations?

Comment: tnx! I just finished doing it, any help sir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem is with URL. 
It work http://www.itrain.com.my/v3/ but doesnt work on http://itrain.com.my/v3/

Set on your server redirection (301) from non-www URL to www URL.

Comment: Redirecting URL on apache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272159/redirecting-url-without-www-to-www

Comment: Indeed, I've just checked and the request is sent to the site with WWW. Firefox will refuse to download the fonts from a different domain. So, the htaccess issue the OP mentioned in a comment to my reply seems like a good place to look for the solution :).

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys! Now my problem is how to write this in web.config RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] .. I really don't know why .htaccess wont execute? from my hosting

Comment: It depends what IIS do you have. http://www.barrywise.com/2008/10/seo-canonical-urls-and-301-redirects-in-windows-iis-6-iis-7/  Some info also here: http://knowledge.freshpromo.ca/seo-tools/301-redirect.php#canonicaliis

Answer (score 1):

I would wager you have the font installed on your local machine. I don't see it on any browser. Instead, I get two 404 errors.

In other words: please make sure the font files are available at the locations their respective locations: `http://www.itrain.com.my/v3/wp-content/themes/itrain/img/fonts/big_noodle_titling-webfont.woff` and `http://www.itrain.com.my/v3/wp-content/themes/itrain/img/fonts/bebas__-webfont.woff`.

[EDIT]

I've just looked at the fonts directory listing on your site. The ttf and eot versionf of your fonts are available, the woff and svg are listed, but result in a 404 error. Furthermore, the ttf version (downloaded instead of woff in Firefox, after getting a 404) seems to generate an empty HTTP response.

So... Make sure the fonts are there, make sure they have proper privileges set (like 0644). I can't see any other issues than the font files themselves as the CSS appears to be correct.

[EDIT 2]

@kubedan provides a great tip that seems to fit your concern about the htaccess: the domain the fonts are downloaded from is always preceded with `www`. Firefox will refuse to download such content, you need to use the same domain.

Comment: Thanks sir! But, I have the .woff file in that folder. Do you think the problem maybe on the Web.config or .htaccess?

Comment: Yes, this might indeed be the cause. Something is preventing them from being downloaded. All I can say is that it's not the CSS.